# Alias not work when i write custom query in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I have the following controller

```
$result = DB::table('customs_duties')
         ->select(DB::raw('sum(cd_cash) as cd_cash'),DB::raw('sum(cd_creditnote) as cd_creditnote'))
         ->where('fiscalyear', 1)->get();
```

I get actual result for two field in:

```
dd($result);
```

but when i want to get specific field result such as

```
dd($result->cd_cash);
```

I have the following error:

> Property [cd_cash] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call ->get(); so you recieve a array.

```
$result = DB::table('customs_duties')->select(DB::raw('sum(cd_cash) as cd_cash'),DB::raw('sum(cd_creditnote) as cd_creditnote'))->where('fiscalyear', 1)->get();    
echo $result[0]->cd_cash;
```

Will return your value, otherwise you can call ->first().

```
$result = DB::table('customs_duties')->select(DB::raw('sum(cd_cash) as cd_cash'),DB::raw('sum(cd_creditnote) as cd_creditnote'))->where('fiscalyear', 1)->first();
echo $result->cd_cash;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$result = DB::table('customs_duties')->select(DB::raw('sum(cd_cash) as cd_cash'),DB::raw('sum(cd_creditnote) as cd_creditnote'))->where('fiscalyear', 1)->first();

dd($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`get` gives you Collection.
You can either use `->first();` function or use `foreach` on your `$result` like: `@foreach ($result as $res) $res->cd_cash`